How do I delete refunded invoices from customer invoices?
I would like to get the following output from the table below: For each customer, the refunded invoices will be removed from the purchased invoices. For example, if a single product is purchased and the same product is refunded, both rows (invoices) will be deleted. However, if 2 products are purchased in a single invoice and one of them is returned, only the refunded invoice will be removed from the table by deducting the refund amount and income (refund invoice) from the invoice containing these 2 product information. I have marked purchased invoices and refunded invoices in the same color.
IsReturn=1 : refunds available
IsReturn=0 : no refunds
ItemCode: product code
ColorCode: product color
ItemDim1Code: product size
Qty: quantity of product purchased

I have also added the same data as table below:



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ApplicationID
ItemCode
ColorCode
ItemDim1Code
Qty
Revenue




15656858
193-R-7-373740
1
11.06.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A1400000002
SYH
50
-1
-699,99


15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A1400000002
SYH
50
2
1.399,98


15656858
193-R-7-373781
1
12.06.2022
D7BD6F42-F1F3-4EC4-9599-AEB000A7CB70
4A2022200036
YVZ
XL
-1
-240,28


15656858
193-R-7-373502
0
10.06.2022
D7BD6F42-F1F3-4EC4-9599-AEB000A7CB70
4A2022200036
YVZ
XL
1
240,28


15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A7020000001
NAT
STN
1
26,95


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200001
BYD
L
1
299,99


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200034
HAK
XL
1
299,99


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
SYH
50
1
699,99


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
ATR
52
1
699,99


21069880
406-R-7-121023
0
4.05.2023
67732FA9-E3CA-4BB1-8C13-AFF800F89C60
4A0121100002
YSL
52
1
199,99


21069880
406-R-7-120741
0
26.04.2023
284DE832-8CE7-41D1-9FCE-AE31011A4AA8
4A1400000001
SYH
56
1
379,99


21069880
1-R-7-16894399
1
26.04.2023
284DE832-8CE7-41D1-9FCE-AE31011A4AA8
4A1400000001
SYH
56
-1
-379,99


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
26.04.2023
9E1674D1-8B70-4BCF-9A82-AFF00112E876
4A1400000001
SYH
52
1
879,99


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A2000000013
amv
XL
3
1.999,86


21069880
1-R-7-16894396
1
7.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A2000000013
amv
XL
-1
-666,62


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A3022100145
GSY
52
1
1.587,20


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
4.05.2023
8C5D271E-30D2-497E-BB0C-AFF800F9EE0B
4A9000000001
GMJ
L
1
359,99



In the end I would like to get an output like the following:



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ApplicationID
ItemCode
ColorCode
ItemDim1Code
Qty
Revenue




15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A1400000002
SYH
50
1
699,99


15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A7020000001
NAT
STN
1
26,95


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200001
BYD
L
1
299,99


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200034
HAK
XL
1
299,99


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
SYH
50
1
699,99


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
ATR
52
1
699,99


21069880
406-R-7-121023
0
4.05.2023
67732FA9-E3CA-4BB1-8C13-AFF800F89C60
4A0121100002
YSL
52
1
199,99


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
26.04.2023
9E1674D1-8B70-4BCF-9A82-AFF00112E876
4A1400000001
SYH
52
1
879,99


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
4.05.2023
8C5D271E-30D2-497E-BB0C-AFF800F9EE0B
4A9000000001
GMJ
L
2
1.333,24


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A3022100145
GSY
52
1
1.587,20


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
4.05.2023
8C5D271E-30D2-497E-BB0C-AFF800F9EE0B
4A9000000001
GMJ
L
1
359,99




Please tag only a single rdbms

Please do not use images... Use table markdown

Is ApplicationID the way to connect invoice and return? I'd probably join invoice with aggregated number of returns and check if SUM(amount returned) >= amount invoice and either adjusted it or removed the row altogether. This can get interesting if you don't have a good return system that properly match products etc

I suspect you have an overly complicated example. You can probably remove the CustomerCode, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, ColorCode, and ItemDim1Code columns and obtain the same logical solution.

A recalculation of QTY and Revenue is required for each CustomerCode,ItemCode,ApplicationID group when a return is present. The sales_data table has 17 rows. 4 rows will be removed due to simple return of exactly want was purchased (AppID ending with 036 and 001). 2 Rows removed due to partial returns (AppID ending with E7F and 621). The final results will have 11 rows. This can be simplified if ApplicationID uniquely  identifies an item purchase or return.
WITH ReturnedItems  AS
(  
--Items that have been returned  
SELECT CustomerCode,ItemCode,ApplicationID, SUM(cast(qty as int)) as NewQty, 
  Sum(Revenue) as NewRevenue
FROM sales_data 
GROUP BY CustomerCode,ItemCode,ApplicationID    
HAVING MAX(IsReturn)=1
)
SELECT s.CustomerCode, 
       s.InvoiceNumber, 
       s.IsReturn, 
       s.InvoiceDate, 
       s.ApplicationID, 
       s.ItemCode, 
       s.ColorCode, 
       s.ItemDim1Code,  
       Isnull(r.NewQty, s.Qty) as QTY, 
       ISNULL(r.NewRevenue,s.Revenue) as Revenue
FROM sales_data s
LEFT JOIN ReturnedItems r ON r.CustomerCode=s.CustomerCode 
                         and r.ItemCode=s.ItemCode
                         and r.ApplicationID=s.ApplicationID  
WHERE IsReturn=0 AND (r.NewQty<>0 or r.NewQty IS NULL )

fiddle



CustomerCode
InvoiceNumber
IsReturn
InvoiceDate
ApplicationID
ItemCode
ColorCode
ItemDim1Code
Qty
Revenue




15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A1400000002
SYH
50
1
699.9900


15656858
193-R-7-372193
0
27.05.2022
DB3A6DCB-7A8C-415C-AF35-AEA200D5FE7F
4A7020000001
NAT
STN
1
26.9500


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200001
BYD
L
1
299.9900


15656858
193-R-7-373782
0
12.06.2022
D832836F-36BB-42ED-B64C-AEB200B6B19F
4A2022200034
HAK
XL
1
299.9900


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
SYH
50
1
699.9900


15656858
193-R-7-373742
0
11.06.2022
00CB6240-D073-4E06-8CA9-AEB10133DE90
4A1400000001
ATR
52
1
699.9900


21069880
406-R-7-121023
0
4.05.2023
67732FA9-E3CA-4BB1-8C13-AFF800F89C60
4A0121100002
YSL
52
1
199.9900


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
26.04.2023
9E1674D1-8B70-4BCF-9A82-AFF00112E876
4A1400000001
SYH
52
1
879.9900


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A2000000013
amv
XL
2
1333.2400


21069880
1-R-7-16853468
0
3.09.2022
F045ED37-E17C-4690-83D9-AF0500A17621
4A3022100145
GSY
52
1
1587.2000


21069880
406-R-7-120740
0
4.05.2023
8C5D271E-30D2-497E-BB0C-AFF800F9EE0B
4A9000000001


0
0.0000




Thank you very much. I was able to get the result I wanted.

WITH n AS (
    SELECT  CustomerCode, ApplicationID, ItemCode, ColorCode, ItemDim1Code, SUM (Qty) Qty, SUM (Revenue) Revenue
    FROM    sales_data
    GROUP BY CustomerCode, ApplicationID, ItemCode, ColorCode, ItemDim1Code
    HAVING SUM(qty) > 0
)
SELECT  n.CustomerCode, s.InvoiceNumber, s.IsReturn, s.InvoiceDate, n.ApplicationID, n.ItemCode, n.ColorCode, n.ItemDim1Code, n.Qty, n.Revenue
FROM    n
    JOIN    sales_data  s
        ON  (   s.CustomerCode  =   n.CustomerCode
            AND s.ApplicationID =   n.ApplicationID
            AND s.ItemCode      =   n.ItemCode
            AND s.ColorCode     =   n.ColorCode
            AND s.ItemDim1Code  =   n.ItemDim1Code
            AND s.IsReturn      =   FALSE
            );



Thanks but it comes in rows with is.Return=1

@burga.varol. amended to meet the need

a nice perspective. thanks it worked
